# How to add XNamespace to XDocument's root element?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm generating Xml Documemnt via Linq To Xml. It is added 'xmlns' attribute to all elements with empty values.
How to remove unwanted attributes?

```
XNamespace np = "example"; 

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty),
                        new XElement(np + "root")
                        );
var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };

foreach (var item in list)
{
  var xE = new XElement("child",
             new XElement("first", item),
             new XElement("second", item)
                        );
   doc.Root.AddFirst(xE);
}
```

I expect the result.

Only xmlns attribute in root element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="example">
  <child>
    <first>3</first>
    <second>3</second>
  </child>
  <child >
    <first>2</first>
    <second>2</second>
  </child>
  <child>
    <first>1</first>
    <second>1</second>
  </child>
</root>
```

But getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns="example">
  <child xmlns=""> //unwanted attribute

    <first>3</first>
    <second>3</second>
  </child>
  <child xmlns="">
    <first>2</first>
    <second>2</second>
  </child>
  <child xmlns="">
    <first>1</first>
    <second>1</second>
  </child>
</root
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML namespace on child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368858/xml-namespace-on-child-element)

Comment: I usually create my XDocument from a string that contains to root tag : XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<root></root>");

Answer (score 1):

It needs to add XNamespace to every XElement.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                   new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", string.Empty),
                       new XElement(np + "root")
                   );
var list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };

foreach (var item in list)
{
 var xE = new XElement(np+"child",
            new XElement(np+"first", item),
            new XElement(np+"second", item)
                       );
  doc.Root.AddFirst(xE);
}
```