# Adding namespace to parent and child nodes in C# during xml serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, serialization

I'm serializing XML from a C# class, and I need to include a namespace in the root and child elements.

When I add a namespace from XmlSerializerNamespaces, it adds all of the namespaces to the root element.

I need to add some namespaces to the root as well as some to the Grouping1 Element.

Thanks

```
<root>
  <Element>
    <Grouping1>
      <Item1>First1</Item1>
      <Item2>Second1</Item2>
    </Grouping1>
    <Grouping2>
      <Item3>Third1</Item3>
    </Grouping2>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <Grouping1>
      <Item1>First2</Item1>
      <Item2>Second2</Item2>
    </Grouping1>
    <Grouping2>
      <Item3>Third2</Item3>
    </Grouping2>
  </Element>
</root>
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces?view=net-6.0&force_isolation=true

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368858/xml-namespace-on-child-element
if true should be not important where the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces can be added to any XML element using XmlNamespaceDeclarations in a child class.

```
 [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
 public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[]{new XmlQualifiedName("sig", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2")});
```

Sample Code

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class RootClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "body", Namespace = "httpenv")]
    public BodyClass body = new BodyClass();
}

[Serializable]
public class BodyClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "element", Namespace = "httpsos")]
    public SOSClass element = new SOSClass();
}

[Serializable]
public class SOSClass
{
    // This will be used by XML serializer to determine the namespaces
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces( new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("sos", "httpsos"), });
}
```